# Adding to SVN en masse from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, addition, bulk

Say I have been working on a project for a while, added a few new files scattered around 3 or 4 packages, and I would like to export. But there is no way that I know of to add all the newly created files to SVN control at once. And eye-hovering through each package's file icons is neither reliable not practical. Any way to do it?

EDIT: sorry about the mingling. So, I wanted to export, not commit.

Comment: Right-click - Team - Commit...? Or open the Team - Synchronize view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Subclipse, you can just commit the whole project (or multiple projects): files which aren't under version control will be added automatically. I don't know if it's the same with other Subversion integrations.

Comment: err, care to take another look over the question ? :D

Comment: Now I don't understand. Subversion "export" means just to copy all the files out of the repository into a plain directory with no `.svn` directories, while Eclipse "export" means to build a product. The first one doesn't make sense if the files aren't *in* the repository, and the second one will just work (but of course has nothing to do with Subversion.) What are you looking to do exactly?

Comment: i am looking for the first one - how tosvn export together with each newly added file ? Probably can't. So how to first add these file en masse, without the need to handpick every one, right click->team->add to svn .. ?

Comment: You're going to have to commit, then export; you can't export what's not in the repository. Just right-click Team | Commit. Alternatively, if for some reason you can't do this, then just copy the files and delete the hidden `.svn` directories (a lot easier on UNIX-like systems than on Windows, granted.)

Comment: well, committing is not an option I am afraid. It seems that all I have to do is take that line from http://www.internetcreators.com/blog/development/bulk-add-missing-files-subversion and put it inside some shell script to do it recursively for each folder. Pretty easy, huh ? [nailbiting]